# Get all nodes from an XML document by using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm using VB.NET with XPath and would like to get a unique list of all nodes within my XML document, including child nodes.

Is this possible with XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all elements:

```
//*
```

To get all nodes, including the root, processing instructions, comments, text nodes, and attributes:

```
//node() | //@*
```